Нужна ли запятая перед союзом ИЛИ в этом предложении?
Учись(?) или пропадёшь.
Тут две основы, но оба глагола относятся к одному лицу...

Это сложное предложение с двумя грамматическими основами, между ними ставится запятая: Голосуй, или проиграешь.

«Учись или проиграешь!» — название видео на YouTube, которое можно посмотреть на платформе.  У односоставных предложений свои правила http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133  У определенно-личных предложений один ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ ДЕЙСТВИЯ.  В каком случае односоставные предложения приравниваются к однородным членам? Ну очень много вопросов, не так все просто, как хотелось бы.

Прочитать еще можно по-разному:  ГолосУй, или проиграешь. Голосуй или проигрАешь.  Да и восклицательный знак здесь не помешает, с ним как быть.

Правильно:
Учись или пропадешь!
Это односоставные определенно-личные предложения (глагол в пов. наклонении и во 2-м лице ед.числа).
Правило:
 3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в 
 сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав 
 в качестве частей входят:
 2) побудительные предложения: Подпустить врага и огонь дать 
 по команде! (Фурм.) — объединяет побудительная интонация; 
 Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло! — объединяет 
 побудительная частица; 

Под правило может подойти предложение с восклицательным знаком (побудительная/восклицательная интонация). Что касается определенно-личных предложений в общем случае, то там желательно иметь одинаковую грамматическую форму,  тогда их можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым: уходи или останься.
Примечание. В то же время графика предложения явно не допускает постановку запятой в таком предложении, уж лучше тире. Из Накорпуса: Машхур, иди учись, или у священника своего муслимского спроси, неуч. В распространенном предложении можно поставить запятую.
Пример: Учись или проиграешь!

Но у меня в предложении нет восклицательного знака, это принципиально.

Тогда пишите без знака и без запятой: Учись или пропадешь, Объяснение: определенно-личные предложения приравниваются к однородным членам, так как один и тот же производитель.  А для однородных сказуемых их форма неважна. Но строгого соответствия правилам нет: ни в ПАС, ни у  Розенталя опреденно-личные предложения не рассматриваются отдельно, Можно с союзом: Учись, а то пропадешь.

Мнение Грамоты: https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/319340

Комментарий
      О правила грамматики! Вдвойне
      Пускай себя проявит ваша сила...

Принятый ответ: Это сложное предложение с двумя грамматическими основами, между ними ставится запятая: Голосуй, или проиграешь.
Мнение Грамоты:  В невосклицательном предложении знак препинания (запятая или тире) нужен, так как не имеется объединяющей интонации.

В приведенных ответах не учитывается, что это односоставные определенно-личные предложения. В таких предложениях один производитель действия, и это может считаться объединяющим фактором. Кроме того, в некоторых случаях их приравнивают  к однородным сказуемым. Определенно-личные предложения не рассмотрены в правилах, в том числе их нет среди побудительных и восклицательных предложений, указанных там.

Поэтому такие предложения должны решаться по особым, а не по общим ПРАВИЛАМ, в том числе относительно восклицательной и побудительной интонации.  Соответственно, я не считаю удовлетворительными оба ответа.

Вполне возможно, что запятая нужна, но требуется корректное обоснование, в том числе с учетом практики письма.

Могу предположить, что при решении надо учитывать однородность предложений, то есть отсутствие взаимообусловленности между ними, а также разную форму сказуемых в приведенных предложениях.  В то же время общим элементом является один производитель действия.


ПРАВИЛА (в них нет ни  одного определенно-личного предложения)
Также обратим внимание на дополнительные структурные элементы, которые характерны для названных предложений (частицы и др.)
Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! – это односоставные инфинитивные предложения
Пункт 3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?;

побудительные предложения: Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! (Фурм.) — объединяет побудительная интонация; Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло! — объединяет побудительная частица; Да будет свято имя героя и память о нём сохранится в веках! — объединяет побудительная частица;

восклицательные предложения: Как он смешон и как глупы его выходки! — объединяет восклицательная интонация; Как часто мы собирались вместе и какие вели интересные беседы!; Сколько скрытого смысла в этих словах и какой отклик вызывают они у слушателей!;


Примечание. О грамматике предложений с союзом ЛИ говорится в теме.

А почему вы считаете, что один производитель действия является общим элементом? Например, в предложении "Он гулял по парку, шуршал листьми, и таким образом он постепенно успокаивался" мы же ставим запятую, хотя речь об одном и том же лице.

Однородные члены предложения, соединенные одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами (и, да  в знач. «и »; или, либо  ) не разделяются запятой: Теплоход встал поперек реки и дал течению развернуть его вниз, по ходу (Расп.); День да ночь – сутки прочь (поел.); Поддержит он Уздечкина или не поддержит ? (Пан.).

А ничего, что тут первый глагол в повелительном наклонении, а второй в изъявительном?

@Серж, вы, как я поняла, приравниваете определенно-личные предложения к однородным членам. При одинаковой форме сказуемых обычно так и происходит,например: "Сам учись или других слушай". Но в нашем случае форма разная. Какие вообще существуют правила в этой теме? Где можно прочитать? Вот задан вопрос относительно разной формы, но ответа никто не дал, хотя тема закрыта.  Сколько раз она уже обсуждалась и заканчивалась ничем,  то есть это постоянный источник для разговоров и в будущем. Может, уже пора грамотно в ней разобраться.

Да, вы правы, это ССП.

Комментарий 2
 А почему вы считаете, что один производитель действия 
 является общим элементом? Например, в предложении "Он гулял 
 по парку, шуршал листьями, и таким образом он постепенно 
 успокаивался" мы же ставим запятую, хотя речь об одном и 
 том же лице. 

(1) В вашем примере  семантический субъект действия один и тот же,  но там два двусоставных предложения, и в каждом свое подлежащее. Это другой случай.
(2) У нас же односоставные определенно-личные предложения с особой грамматикой (лицо грамматически обозначено), для которых нет решения в справочнике, в то время как остальные виды односоставных предложений расписаны. Я не предлагаю своего решения, но меня удивляет, с какой легкостью задачу решают другие пользователи.
(3) Автор принятого ответа не считает, что односоставные определенно-личные предложения заслуживают особого внимания. (Возможно, он  вообще не знает, что они определенно-личные.)
(3) Грамота тоже так считает, но вдобавок решение связывает с интонацией. Но разве не видно, что в правилах о разных видах интонации нет ни одного определенно-личного предложения, а в других предложениях дополнительно используются частицы.  То есть эти предложения построены определенным образом, а не просто знак поставлен.
(4) Допустим, что определенно-личные предложения действительно должны подчиняться общим правилам, но факты против этого. Некоторые из них приравниваются к сказуемым, другие под вопросом.  Да и практика письма неоднозначна.
Любопытные замечания из справочников. ПАС: 4) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения с ОДИНАКОВОЙ ФОРМОЙ сказуемого: С деревьев капало и вокруг пахло листвой; Зрителей разместили вокруг арены и на арену вывели участников представления;
Розенталь: односоставные неопределенно-личные предложения (если МЫСЛИТСЯ один и тот же производитель действия): Стали искать черкесов во всех углах и, разумеется, ничего не нашли (Л.);

Ну в ПАС же чёткро сказано: если части СПП представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения с ОДИНАКОВОЙ ФОРМОЙ сказуемого (то запятая не ставится). А у нас РАЗНЫЕ формы сказуемого. Исчерпывающий ответ дан в правилах. Грамота и раньше отвечала на подобные вопросы: https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/287684#question , https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/311415#question , https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/279204#question Всё-таки это официальная служба, на которую корректорам надо ориентироваться. Если правила хромают, то надо их менять, а своё вИдение может быть у каждого.

Не ставится, да.  Но это другой вид предложения, или это не имеет значения, можно по аналогии? Теперь об исчерпывающих ответах. Я бы и хотела бы на них ориентироваться, но как)  Они очень редко пишут объяснения.  У нас всегда выбор фифти-фифти, а причины могут быть разные. Приходи, и увидишь их сам. А если у меня: Приходи, и увидишь. Или: Приходи и смотри.  Почему разные решения, пусть напишут, а на честное слово я не верю. И почему они вам про интонацию написали?  Тоже ребус. Да уж, исчерпывающие у них ответы) Про союз ИЛИ у них ничего нет? Или тоже по аналогии? Но союз ИЛИ не так-то прост)

Они обобщили все такие случаи. Про интонацию написали, потому что я сама подчеркнула, что "интересует именно не восклицательное предложение".

Прекрасно? Вы ими довольны, не правда ли?  А у Розенталя правила хромают, да?  Я вас правильно поняла?   Но тогда лучше у них спрашивать, мы-то по правилам работаем и Розенталя не правим. Но вот мне кажется, что  у них проблемы, а не у Розенталя.  И вообще лингвистам  такого уровня надо больше присматриваться к практике  и к проверенным правилам, а не свои обобщения писать.  Все правила основаны на грамматике, а ею занимаются серьезные специалисты, не им чета.  Вот и пусть не просто предложения пишут, что запятая нужна, а грамматическое обоснование дают.

И обобщение по-другому выглядит. Какой смысл  во всех темах, где корректируется постановка запятой в ССП? Думаю, это приравнивание простых предложений к однородным членам. И во всех темах надо увидеть это приравнивание и особенности решения расписать. Даже темы, связанные с интонацией, имеют свои структурные признаки, это не просто знак поставить или стереть. Вот и пусть допишут грамматическое решение для односоставных определенно-личных предложений.

Увы, нет, вы неправильно меня поняли :(  Я, наоборот, написала, что в правилах дан исчерпывающий ответ. Пусть Грамота даёт грамматическое обоснование, я только за. Но мне кажется, они побоятся отсебятину писать.
